# Adding and Removing MySQL Databases via CentOS 6 - 64 bit

Tags: centos, mysql, database, centos6, centos5

I have a VPS, and am having troubles with MySQL. I think I have created a database, but got lost.

I need to know how to:

- Add a database, with the username, name of the database, and password.
- Remove a database.

Comment: could you please throw more light into this? Say what you tried? What is the problem your are facing? Kindly update with more information

Comment: Have you tried searching for how to do this and learning through online resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using mysql from the command line, you would connect to your mysql server with
`mysql -u USER -p PASS`

if that works you're at a mysql prompt >
type `CREATE DATABASE my_new_database_name;`
Then use a GRANT statement to create a new user with access only to that database; eg
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_new_database_name.* TO 'new_user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_new_database_name.* TO 'new_user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`

You can see what databases you have with:
`show databases;`
and you can delete a database with `DROP DATABASE my_new_database_name;`